# Video captured from Android screen recorder can not be played on web browser

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, screen-recording, android-mediaprojection

I encounter a problem when I try to play a video on a web browser in a  component, the file can not play at all. The file was captured on Android device using MediaRecorder and MediaProjection and tried to record screen.
Here is the code how I initialize the MediaRecorder:

```
public class ScreenRecordService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = ScreenRecordService.class.getSimpleName();

private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
private static final int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 960;
private static final int DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 540;

private float mDensity;
private int mRotation;
private boolean mIsRecording;

private MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;
private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
private MediaProjectionCallback mMediaProjectionCallback;
private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
private String mFilePath;

static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}

private class MediaProjectionCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        try {
            if (mIsRecording) {
                mIsRecording = false;
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
                mMediaRecorder.reset();
            }
            mMediaProjection = null;
            stopScreenSharing();

            HermesEventBus.getDefault().post(new EventRecorder.Server(EventRecorder.SERVER_STOP_SUCCESS));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            HermesEventBus.getDefault().post(new EventRecorder.Server(EventRecorder.SERVER_STOP_FAIL));
        }
    }
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onStopCall(EventRecorder.Client clientEvent) {
    if (clientEvent.messageType == EventRecorder.CLIENT_STOP_RECORD) {
        stopRecording();
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    HermesEventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    AppManager.getInstance().addService(this);
    mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (mProjectionManager == null) {
        mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    }
    if (intent != null) {
        mDensity = intent.getFloatExtra("density", 0f);
        mRotation = intent.getIntExtra("rotation", 0);
        mFilePath = intent.getStringExtra(Const.Intent.INFO);
        JLog.d(TAG, mFilePath);

        startRecording(intent);
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    AppManager.getInstance().removeService(this);
}

private void startRecording(Intent intent) {
    try {
        if (!mIsRecording) {
            mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(RESULT_OK, intent);
            mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);
            initRecorder();
            mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
            mIsRecording = true;

            HermesEventBus.getDefault().post(new EventRecorder.Server(EventRecorder.SERVER_START_SUCCESS));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mIsRecording = false;
        HermesEventBus.getDefault().post(new EventRecorder.Server(EventRecorder.SERVER_START_FAIL));
    }
}

private void stopRecording() {
    try {
        if (mIsRecording) {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
            stopScreenSharing();

            HermesEventBus.getDefault().post(new EventRecorder.Server(EventRecorder.SERVER_STOP_SUCCESS));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mIsRecording = false;
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
        }
        stopScreenSharing();
        HermesEventBus.getDefault().post(new EventRecorder.Server(EventRecorder.SERVER_STOP_FAIL));
    }
}

private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay() {
    return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(getString(R.string.video_record), DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, (int) mDensity,
            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null, null);
}

private void stopScreenSharing() {
    if (mVirtualDisplay == null) {
        return;
    }
    mVirtualDisplay.release();
    destroyMediaProjection();
    mIsRecording = false;
}

private void initRecorder() {
    int bitRateQuality = PrefsUtils.getInstance(this, Const.Pref.FILE_COMMON).getInt(Const.Pref.KEY_RECORD_BITRATE, Const.Setting.QUALITY_MID);
    int bitRate;
    if (bitRateQuality == Const.Setting.QUALITY_HIGH) {
        bitRate = 1536000;
    } else if (bitRateQuality == Const.Setting.QUALITY_MID) {
        bitRate = 1024 * 1024;
    } else {
        bitRate = 512000;
    }
    if (mMediaRecorder == null) {
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    }
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4); //THREE_GPP
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mFilePath);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(8); // 30
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(bitRate);
        int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(mRotation + 90);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener((mr, what, extra) -> {
            if (what == MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED) {
                stopRecording();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void destroyMediaProjection() {
    if (mMediaProjection != null) {
        mMediaProjection.unregisterCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback);
        mMediaProjection.stop();
        mMediaProjection = null;
    }
    JLog.i(TAG, "MediaProjection Stopped");
}
```

}

And here is the file I uploaded.

```
http://eachdoctorvideotest.oss-cn-shenzhen.aliyuncs.com/1103/videoRecord/input/ali_TVM1103vRecordIn20190212154904841.mp4
```

Just paste the url to any browser(I use Chrome and chrome cannot play but Safari can) and you can find that the file can not play. But you can play it on any third party media player on PC. So, what's the exact problem that the file can not be played on browser?

This video file was originally generated with two files(video track and audio track). 
I use mp4parser to combine there tracks and you may see the library here:

```
https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser
```

Here is the key code I used to combine them:

```
    public boolean muxAacMp4(String mp4Path, String aacPath, String outPath) {
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        AACTrackImpl aacTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(aacPath));
        Movie videoMovie = MovieCreator.build(mp4Path);
        Track videoTracks = null;
        for (Track videoMovieTrack : videoMovie.getTracks()) {
            if ("vide".equals(videoMovieTrack.getHandler())) {
                videoTracks = videoMovieTrack;
            }
        }

        Movie resultMovie = new Movie();
        resultMovie.addTrack(videoTracks);
        resultMovie.addTrack(aacTrack);

        Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(resultMovie);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(outPath));
        out.writeContainer(fos.getChannel());
        fos.close();
        flag = true;
        Log.e("update_tag", "merge finish");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: that is not a problem, as the browser does not have to play all possible formats. Either you need to record it in the browser-supported format, or use the video player to play it (not a browser)

Comment: hum.. I know the browser can not support all the formats, but the MediaRecorder can only provide limit format support and mp4 is a common format I believe. I'm finding whether any problem in my code. Also, playing on browser is the function that our platform really needed. I'm also thinking about trans coding the video file which is really complex. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put an `'error'` handler on your HTML5 video element, you can see this file produces the following error (Chrome 71):

> `Error 3; details: PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: Failed to send audio packet for decoding: timestamp=0 duration=32000 size=2 side_data_size=0 is_key_frame=1 encrypted=0 discard_padding (us)=(0, 0)`

(FYI: A similar error is discussed on github [here](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/1529)).

2 bytes is kinda small for an audio sample. A little digging reveals that this is actually a copy of the "Audio Specific Config" for your audio track, which is strange, because that information is already present in the .mp4 headers. It's being duplicated into a sample at timestamp 0 (the first sample); I'm not sure why.

You may want to take a look at the docs for [`setAudioEncoder()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setAudioEncoder(int)); you have not called it, and the docs state:

> If this method is not called, the output file will not contain an audio track.

Yet, your file contains an audio track. So, this may warrant a little further investigation.

**EDIT**

Given this new understanding of your problem, it appears that the most expedient solution is just to forcibly drop the first sample from your AAC stream. Might as well do it with your "combining" code. I would subclass the `AACTrackImpl` like this:

```
AACTrackImpl aacTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(aacPath)) {
    boolean mAltered = false;
    @Override
    List<Sample> getSamples() {
        List<Samples> samples = super.getSamples();
        if(!mAltered)
        {
            samples.remove(0);
            mAltered=true;
        }
        return samples;
    }
};
```

I haven't tested this code. Really quite a hack-y solution, that relies on a number of assumptions. It takes advantage of the fact that all the samples in your AAC track happen to have the same "duration"; otherwise, you'd have to override `getSampleDurations()`, too, using a similar technique.

Since we dropped a sample but didn't alter the timestamps, this will shift all your audio by ~23ms. In this case, since we don't exactly know why your audio encoder exhibited this behavior in the first place, this could be interpreted either as causing a timing problem, or as fixing one.

Comment: Thanks for such a professional answer. I believe there's problem on the audio track as you stated. I had not called setAudioEncoder() cause the video track and audio are separate in two files due to they were captured in different source. When I done recording, I use mp4parser to combine them into 1 file. Now I'm really wondering the problem is on the combining config.

Comment: I don't think `mp4parser` added in that first sample. It was probably already present in your `aacPath` file. Let's have a look at the code you used to make that recording.

Comment: I already edited my question and enrich my code on recording screen. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. I'm asking about the code you use to record audio.

Comment: Sorry, my fault! I have not implemented the code to record audio. The audio file came from third party SDK which is meeting related. I can not access any detail about how it record audio so I'm not able to provide that for you.

Comment: Oh man, this really did the trick though there are still lots of test need to be done.  My file is at least playable on Chrome now. Thank you so much for your help.